# Select where equal AND not equal

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (n:m) named **group**, like this:

```
group_id    type
-------------------------
53          7
152         7
301         7
....        ...
53          12
```

EDITED:

I want to select all the rows where the group contains the type **7** but, if the group contains the type 12, i wan to exclude it

The output should be:

```
group_id    type
-------------------------
152         7
301         7
```

I've created a query

```
SELECT *
FROM group AS g
WHERE g.type= 7 AND g.type!= 12
```

But, i'm getting

```
group_id    type
-------------------------
53          7
152         7
301         7
```

Any idea why?

Comment: do you want to get type is equal to 7 or not equal to 12 ah?

Comment: Every row only has one type. If it's equal to 7, then it obviously isn't equal to 12.

Comment: i want to return the rows where the group_id type = 7 but exclude those groups that also have type 12

Comment: Fix the question to say what you really mean.

Comment: i've edited the question.. sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. One is to perform a `LEFT JOIN` joining two instances of the table, limiting one side to `type = 7` and the other to `type = 12`, and looking for a non-match on the side limited to `type = 12`.

```
SELECT
  g1.*
FROM
  `group` g1
   LEFT JOIN `group` g2 ON g1.group_id = g2.group_id AND g2.type = 12
WHERE
   g1.type = 7
   /* NULL means no match in the 12's */
   AND g2.group_id IS NULL
```

Here's a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2549ce/2

It can also be done with a `NOT EXISTS`, relating the subquery to the outer via `group_id`.

```
SELECT
  g.*
FROM 
  `group` g
WHERE
  g.type = 7
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT group_id FROM `group` g2 WHERE type = 12 AND g.group_id = g2.group_id
  )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2549ce/7

Comment: is NOT EXISTS faster than NOT IN ? just asking

Comment: @Marco http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: ok, thanks. According to the article a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL is the prefer way. Thanks again

Comment: yeap! tested on my development server and the LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is noticeble faster!

Answer (score 5):

there are several ways to do this NOT IN is one

```
SELECT *
FROM group AS g
WHERE g.type= 7 
and group_id not in (select group_id from group where g.type = 12)
```